# Testcafe - dealing with video

Tags: javascript, video, jquery-selectors, testcafe, current-time

I'm testing a page with an embedded video where using the console I can play, stop, and get the current playing time.

When I try to translate that to Testcafe, I get errors. Here's what I have working on the console:

```
var vid = document.querySelector('.video-tech')
if (vid.paused === false) {
  vid.pause();
} else {
  vid.play();
}
document.querySelector('.video-current-time-display').innerText // 0:33
```

Then I try to get these elements using the Testcafe syntax:

```
const playVideo = ClientFunction(() => {
      document.querySelector('.video-tech').play();
    });

const pauseVideo = ClientFunction(() => {
      document.querySelector('.video-tech').pause();
    });
```

So far so good. The problem is that I cannot work with an If-Else statement and the `ClientFunction`.

My goal is to get the text from the `current-time-display` and let the vide play for a few seconds, then stop.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a browser policy limitation, you might need to specify (in case of Chrome browser) the `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` flag (chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy):

```
testcafe "chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required" test.js
```

See also: [Start a Browser With Arguments](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#start-a-browser-with-arguments)